# "if not in" in python to get the index

Tags: python

I want to use "if not in" syntax in python but what I want to do is to if the element is found in list I want to get the index.

for example

```
if 3 not in [2,3,4]:
    print "hello"
```

If 3 is found in list I want to get the index which in this case is 1.

Comment: `else:at_index = [2,3,4].index(3)`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a=[2,3,4]
>>> a.index(3)
1
```

**EDIT**

```
>>> a=[2,3,4]
>>> def check(n):
...     try:
...             print a.index(n)
...     except ValueError:
...             print "Element not found in list a"
... 
>>> check(5)
Element not found in list a
>>> check(3)
1
```

Comment: Better use it with try-except.

Comment: This raises a ValueError exception if the element sought is not found.